# How to prevent underscore.js templates to create undesired blank lines?

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, underscore.js, yeoman

I am creating a generator using Yeoman, which in turn uses underscore.js templates.
In a given file I have this code:

```
var
    <% _.each(requires, function(require) { %>
    <% if(require.shouldApply) { %>
    <%= _.camelize(require.name) %> = require('<%= require.name %>'),
    <% } %>
    <% }); %>
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

Given that `require.shouldApply` sometimes is false I don't want a blank line to be produced.

So for example, for the input `requires: [{shouldApply: false, name: 'zoo'}, {shouldApply: false, name: 'foo'}, {shouldApply: true, name: 'bar'}]` I get this:

```
var
    zoo = require('zoo'), //note that the line below is blank

    bar = require('bar'), //I don't want the blank line above
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

Does anyone know how to prevent underscore.js templates to create these undesired blank lines?

Comment: If you put the `if` statement (with it's content) all on one line, do you still get the extra line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JSP we sometimes use the (annoying) practice of extending the template-tag onto the next line to prevent this.

It's not ideal for readability, but it does solve the 'unwanted newline' problem.

For example:

```
<% if(require.shouldApply) { 
%><%= _.camelize(require.name) %> = require('<%= require.name %>'), 
<% } %>
```

In JSP we also have `trimDirectiveWhitespaces` and similar options -- which aren't perfect, but do help. Your templating system may also have something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to cut down what is passed into your _.each loop so that you only are generating items that should be shown.

```
<% _.each(_.where(requires, {shouldApply: true}), function(require){ %>
```

Comment: This is why I like Lo-Dash's automatic chaining so much more than Underscore:  
`<% _(requires).where({shouldApply: true}).each(function(require){ %>`

Comment: I have just found out that even without the `if` line I still keep getting unwanted blank lines!!! Can't understand why..!

Comment: Underscore has chaining also

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two line returns outside the if statement that will be produced for each item in the array:

```
var
<% _.each(requires, function(require) { %> // New Line Here
<% if(require.shouldApply) { %>
<%= _.camelize(require.name) %> = require('<%= require.name %>'),
<% } %> // New Line Here
<% }); %>
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

So if you condense them down to:

```
var <% _.each(requires, function(require) { if(require.shouldApply) { %>
<%= _.camelize(require.name) %> = require('<%= require.name %>'),
<% } }); %>
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

That should stop the surplus output.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of Yeoman, an alternative is to register a stream that will clean up multiple blank lines in the generated artifacts after the fact. That leaves you free to structure the <% %> code in your templates more naturally.

The example below uses gulp-replace in a transform stream. It employs a regex to replace double line breaks with single line breaks in all files.

```js
'use strict';
var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');
var chalk = require('chalk');
var yosay = require('yosay');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

module.exports = yeoman.Base.extend({

  writing: function() {

    this.registerTransformStream(replace(/\r\n\s*\r\n/g, '\r\n'));

    this.fs.copyTpl(
      this.templatePath('_someTemplate.js'),
      this.destinationPath('someFinalArtifact.js'), {
        nameSpace: nameSpace
      }
    );
  }
});
```

Don't forget to add gulp-replace in the generator's package.json.

Reference: "Transform output files through streams" at http://yeoman.io/authoring/file-system.html.